# Interpreter throwing error after running the code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried the following code:

```py
name = input("What's your name? ")
print("hello,")
print(name)
```

Output

```py
>>> & C:/Users/Vaib/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe d:/Python/hello.py
>>> File "\<stdin\>", line 1
>>> & C:/Users/Vaib/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe d:/Python/hello.py
>>> ^
>>> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When using the debug option, code works, but when using the run option, the following syntax error message is displayed:

[image]

I expected a smooth output, but instead got a syntax error.

Comment: What happens if you remove the empty line at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Are you trying to execute it manually via typing in the terminal, or by clicking on the "run" icon in the top right?

Comment: Close your terminals and click the run button. Then it'll start a powershell window and run the script. You cannot run the program while running a Python terminal.

Comment: You are running bash code in the python interpreter which, by definition, expects python code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your vscode terminal is running `Python` instead of `PowerShell` and it trys to run a powershell command through the python shell which will simply not work.

I believe that you accidentally ran `python3` on your teminal so all you need to do is to run `exit()` to exist the python shell and it will return to powershell

You could also run this manually if you'd like in the following syntax **(in CMD or PowerShell)**

```
C:\Users\Vaib\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.11 "d:\Python\hello.py"
```